# Minix current time

Tags: c, unix, unix-timestamp, minix

How to write current time in `printf` on Minix 3.2.1?
I try to use `gmtime` like below but it gives error on `time(&nowtime)`.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

struct tm *now;
time_t nowtime;
time(&nowtime);
now=gmtime(&nowtime);

printf("TIME is NOW %s",now);
```

Moreover, I try to recall that in kernel (/usr/src/kernel/main.c) because I need that time on the booting of minix to say when the kernel process is finished and switch to user.

I take some errors on above code like when rebuild the kernel like below;

[image]

Comment: 1) Does code include `<time.h>`?  2) post the error message.

Comment: yes time.h is included
for struct tm *now  give error redefinition of 'now' with a different type.  I also change now with nowwwww but still give same error

Comment: There seems to be a contradiction: "gives error on `time(&nowtime)`" and  "`struct tm *now` give error redefinition of 'now'". Suspect error is _not_ on `time(&nowtime)`.

Comment: Expand that to a complete compilable program (it should only take a few more lines), and copy-and-paste the exact error message into your question.

Comment: Maybe [Redefinition of typedef error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719410/redefinition-of-typedef-error)

Comment: You cannot have statements outside a function definition. If you wrap everything other than the `#include`s in `int main(void) {` ... `}`, it should compile (but you'll get garbage from the `printf`; since `now` doesn't point to a string). You don't need `#include <sys/time.h>`. You *do* need `#include <stdio.h>`. If you need to do this *in the kernel* (which you didn't initially mention), the things are going to be different. Finally, a screenshot of your error messages is much less useful than copy-and-pasted text.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8CYZLDXg -- This is a complete self-contained program that should compile and run without error. This is userspace code; it won't work if it's incorporated into the kernel. If you're doing kernel programming, that's going to affect what you need to do, and you need to update your question to make it clearer what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not that familiar with minix, but it is similar to Unix & Linux, so maybe something from that platform may be present on minix... so A couple of approaches

- Run a man on `ctime`
- the man page on Linux's `time()` command contains this example code (which you may have to modify for minix, but it shows how to use `asctime()` `localtime()`  and `time()` ):

  ```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <time.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        time_t result;

        result = time(NULL);
        printf("%s%ju secs since the Epoch\n",
            asctime(localtime(&result)),
                (uintmax_t)result);
        return(0);
    }
  ```

Comment: That's not particularly helpful. The code in the question uses the `time` and `gmtime` functions correctly. The problem is in something the OP hasn't yet shown us.

Comment: I installed minix 3.3 in a virtualbox, compiled and ran a "slightly" modified version of the Linux example code shown above, and it worked successfully.  Perhaps the OP could state a little more succinctly what problem he is having, and the specific error code he is getting, and what he is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Tony maybe the issue with version I used but I also try your one but it fails because says result=time(NULL) expect int or known type.. It can be runable on Linux but minix cannot recognize completely or I miss something else

Comment: Moreover I modified problem of mine more detailed way

Comment: What version of minix are you using...???  Also you say "...it fails because says result=time(NULL) expect int or known type."  I assume you are paraphrasing a compiler error.  Which compiler are you using and what is the exact text of the error???  also Please confirm you are compiling on Minix, and not cross-compiling on another platform... and, are you compiling for PC architecture or ARM architecture...???